# Installing memcached deamon on Centos PHP conflicts

Tags: memcached, php53

I have Centos 5.10 installed on my server and tried running the following command

```
yum install php53u-pecl-memcached.x86_64
Setting up Install Process
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php53u-pecl-memcached.x86_64 0:1.0.0-3.ius.centos5 set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: php53u-zend-abi = 20090626 for package: php53u-pecl-memcached
--> Processing Dependency: libmemcached.so.2(libmemcached_2)(64bit) for package: php53u-pecl-memcached
--> Processing Dependency: libmemcached.so.2()(64bit) for package: php53u-pecl-memcached
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php53u-common.x86_64 0:5.3.28-1.ius.centos5 set to be updated
---> Package php53u-pecl-memcached.x86_64 0:1.0.0-3.ius.centos5 set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: libmemcached.so.2(libmemcached_2)(64bit) for package: php53u-pecl-memcached
--> Processing Dependency: libmemcached.so.2()(64bit) for package: php53u-pecl-memcached
--> Processing Conflict: php53-common conflicts php-common
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
php53-common-5.3.3-22.el5_10.x86_64 from installed has depsolving problems
  --> php53-common conflicts with php53u-common
php53u-pecl-memcached-1.0.0-3.ius.centos5.x86_64 from ius has depsolving problems
  --> Missing Dependency: libmemcached.so.2()(64bit) is needed by package php53u-pecl-memcached-1.0.0-3.ius.centos5.x86_64 (ius)
php53u-pecl-memcached-1.0.0-3.ius.centos5.x86_64 from ius has depsolving problems
  --> Missing Dependency: libmemcached.so.2(libmemcached_2)(64bit) is needed by package php53u-pecl-memcached-1.0.0-3.ius.centos5.x86_64 (ius)
Error: php53-common conflicts with php53u-common
Error: Missing Dependency: libmemcached.so.2(libmemcached_2)(64bit) is needed by package php53u-pecl-memcached-1.0.0-3.ius.centos5.x86_64 (ius)
Error: Missing Dependency: libmemcached.so.2()(64bit) is needed by package php53u-pecl-memcached-1.0.0-3.ius.centos5.x86_64 (ius)
```

So I get a few error regarding php conflicts and missing dependencies.

```
php53-common conflicts php-common
php53-common conflicts with php53u-common
```

Trying to remove packages

```
yum remove php-common
yum remove php53-common
```

Both command result in

```
Package(s) php-common available, but not installed.
Package(s) php53u-common available, but not installed.
No Packages marked for removal
```

How can there be a conflict if the package is not installed?
I can remove php53-common, but this will also remove the dependencies, which is a pleks installation and I don't want to remove that.

What is the best thing I can do now?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe was installed manually from source or using an rpm possibly?

Try the following for example..

```
rpm -qa php-common

rpm -qa php53-common
```

Then try removing by doing the following...

```
sudo rpm -e `rpm -qa | grep -i php-common `

sudo rpm -e `rpm -qa | grep -i php53-common `
```

If it was installed from source for some crazy reason then you might have a battle on your hands!

Good luck :)

Comment: Thnx! I got the conflicts resolved so far. I removed all php packages and installed php53u. Then i reinstalled plesk and ignored the php53 support because plesk otherwise removed the php53u version. I only have the  libmemcached.so.2 dependency error left.

Answer (score 0):

`libmemcached.so.2` is provided by `libmemcached`

see the following

```
[mike@mem01-east ~]$ rpm -qf /usr/lib64/libmemcached.so.2
libmemcached-0.31-1.1.el6.x86_64
```